# Posting complex form data to a RESTful API with AngularJS and Express

Tags: angularjs, express, sails.js, waterline

I'll try to make this question as quick as possible, but its quite complex. I have an api to which I am trying to POST nested data, but I can't figure out how to structure the data properly to do so.

So I've built an API for a survey making application. The generaly structure is User --> Quiz --> Question --> QuestionChoice, with each --> representing a one-to-many relationship.

All of the models for the API look similar, so I won't post them here, but here is an example of one. I built the API using SailsJS and the Waterline ORM. I've tested this with direct requests from the browser, and the API and database are currently working fine, so my problem is on the front end.

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        title: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        is_active: {
            type: 'boolean',
            defaultsTo: 'false'
        },

        quiz: {
            model: 'quiz',
            required: true
        },

        choices: {
            collection: 'questionchoice',
            via: 'question'
        }

    }
};
```

Okay, so on the front end, I have a complex nested form in which the user builds quiz data. Here is an abbreviated version of it:

```
form(name='newQuiz' ng-submit='createNewQuiz()')
    input.quiz-name(type='text', name='name', class='form-control' ng-model='quiz.name' placeholder='SURVEY NAME')
    .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.question-column
        input.question-input(placeholder='QUESTION ONE', type='text', name='question', class='form-control', ng-model="quiz.q1.question")
    .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.answer-column
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE A', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control', ng-model="quiz.q1.answers.a")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE B', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q1.answers.b")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE C', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q1.answers.c")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE D', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q1.answers.d")
    .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.question-column
        input.question-input(placeholder='QUESTION ONE', type='text', name='question', class='form-control', ng-model="quiz.q2.question")
    .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.answer-column
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE A', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control', ng-model="quiz.q2.answers.a")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE B', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q2.answers.b")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE C', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q2.answers.c")
        input.answer-input(placeholder='ANSWER CHOICE D', type='text', name='answer', class='form-control' ng-model="quiz.q2.answers.d")
    .button-row
        input.btn.btn-primary.launch-button(type='submit', value='Save Quiz', class='btn btn-primary')
        input.btn.btn-primary.launch-button(class='btn btn-primary' value='Go Live!')
```

Now, here is where I'm a  bit unclear. The createNewQuiz function that runs on form submission. So my question is, how can I structure the data here so that it will be accepted by my API. Nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

```
$scope.createNewQuiz = function() {
    console.log($scope.currentUser)
    console.log($scope.quiz)
    var newQuiz = {
        user: $scope.currentUser,
        name: $scope.quizName,
        questions: //No idea what to put here
        }

    $http.post('http://localhost:1337/quiz/create', newQuiz)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
            alert('new quiz created');
        }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
            alert('error creating new quiz')
            console.log(data, status, headers)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is nested very deep `User --> Quiz --> Question --> QuestionChoice` and Waterline can't handle it by default. You should handle it by modifiying default Blueprint API at create and/or update action.

1. You can put your nested data in your request by Angular
2. You must override default Blueprint create and/or update (if user can update it) by your self that meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can find more information about writing a custom API endpoint for Sails? Can't seem to find anything that deals with complex/nested data.

Comment: You can look at [Sails's docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res) or [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express).

Comment: If you want to override `update` actions, just write `update` method in your related controller. Like `module.exports = { update: function(req, res) { /* handle here */ } }`

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting your answer as it pointed me in the right direction. I'll post my code including the custom API endpoints and some Angular data modelling on the front-end once I'm finished writing it.